# Group by in Linq with condition

Tags: c#, linq

I want to group by a table with Order Id but if one of price is negative don’t group by and brings all rows in output

I use below code but group by all order id

```
tblResult = tblResult.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(r => new { orderId = r["OrderID"] }).Select(g =>
                {
                    var row = tblResult.NewRow();
                    row["Order ID"] = g.Key.orderId;
                    row["Price"] = g.Sum(r => float.Parse(r.Field<string>("Price"))).ToString();
                    return row;
                }).CopyToDataTable();
```

[image]

Comment: You are expecting a custom `GroupBy` clause. You can't do that using standard extensions. Either you have to create your own extension or create a function to do the `GroupBy`.

Comment: try to group by id where price > 0 union select where price < 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your condition in grouping, the tricky part is the result would be a list for those with negative prices and single item for those without it. if we also make single items as list then `SelectMany()` shoud do what you want:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
             .SelectMany(g => g.Any(x => x.Price < 0)?
                         g.ToList():
                         new List<Order> { new Order { Id = g.Key, Price = g.Sum(grp => grp.Price)}});
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nroRYx)